# can not navigate to code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-navigation

All,
I had imported the source code for jbpm as a project in Eclipse.
earlier I was able to navigate through the code by holding down the Ctrl key on a class name and clicking on it...

I recently had to re-structure my code base and had to re-import the jbpm4 code base as a project...

Strangely the navigation does not work any more, any suggestion what I might be missing?

Comment: Tried rebuilding your project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug on some eclipse versions where the 'go to declaration' suddenly stops working.  The only workaround I've found is to close and open the editor window, then it will work again